# Accessing XAML Object in another CS File

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, blend

I need to change the fill of a rectangle from another CS file. A static method in xaml.cs cannot allow access to the Rectangle Object.

```
public void changeStatusIndicator()
    {
    this.StatusIndicator.Fill = new SlidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(100,0,0));
}
```

I need to call this function from another CS file.

[Edit] 
I want to change the fill property of the Rectangle form another CS File.

Comment: Dependency Property may be helpful

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can send your class reference to the other file, but this is not recommended.
The best solution would be to use the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern.